# Django admin form custom select

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm learning how to use the Django 1.8 admin site. I have created the following model and model admin classes:

```
#models.py
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

#admin.py
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer', 'model')
    exclude = ('owner',)
```

The problem is that my admin form contains all data from Car table but I want to show only rows with owner not null. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method of the model admin class.

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer', 'model')
    exclude = ('owner',)  # note you need a comma to make this a tuple

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.objects.filter(owner__isnull=False)
```

Note it might not be a good idea to change the queryset like this -- if you need to add an owner later on, you won't be able to access those cars in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

The `ModelAdmin` class has a `.get_queryset()` method, you could try writting your own queryset:

```
#admin.py
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer', 'model')
    exclude = ('owner')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Car.objects.exclude(owner=None)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but i had to add request to get_queryset method. Thanks!